# Special methods in python equivalent in c#. (__eq__ and other functions like that)

Tags: c#, python

In python you can do

```
class example:

  def __init__(self):
    self.list = [1, 2, 3, 4]

  def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.list == other.list

  def __add__(self, other):
    return self.list + other
```

by this I mean the special methods. Is it possible to do these sorts of special methods that work with inbuilt operators like + - == in c# such that you could do this sort of thing

```
class example {
  private int[] list = {1, 2, 3, 4};

  public bool __eq__ (int[] otherList){
    return list == otherList;
  }

}
```

This would really help me out if somebody does know the answer, thanks!.

(edit) I am sorry I am a bit of an idiot and did not think to look up operator overloading in c# even though that is exactly what I should have done. Thank you to those who have answered and here is and article if you have the same problem as me and did not realize to look it up in a sensible manner. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_operator_overloading.htm

Comment: Have you looked up anything? [Operator overloading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/overloadable-operators)?

Answer (score 1):

A Google search on the exact keywords in your question gets you this: [C# Operator Overloading](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_operator_overloading.htm) 
You can follow the tutorial to understand further.